# How much height does a newLine() occupy in apache pdfBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to keep track of the y-coordinate when generating pdf. 
This is how I am currently doing it.

```
    PDRectangle mediabox = page.findMediaBox();
    float margin = 15;
    float y = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;
    float fontSize = 10f;
    PDType1Font font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    contentStream.showText("Hello");
    y = y - fontSize;           //decrease y-coordinate
    contentStream.newLine();    //go to new line
    contentStream.showText("World!");
    y = y - fontSize;           //decrease y-coordinate
```

What is the height of new line so that I can precisely keep track of the y-coordinate?

I need something like this.

```
    contentStream.showText("Hello");
    y = y - fontSize;           //decrease y-coordinate
    contentStream.newLine();    //go to new line
    y = y - newLineSize;        <---- require the height of new line.
    contentStream.showText("World!");
    y = y - fontSize;           //decrease y-coordinate
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator created by `newLine()` starts a new line taking the start of the current line and subtracting the *leading* from the **y** coordinate, a value you can set using `setLeading`.